# C Take 3 string inputs then place in character array

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I am trying to take 3 string inputs from a user than pass these values into an array pointer.

However when I pass the values I am getting a null reference. I have researched this issue and have found some solutions using strcpy(). But implementing them has not worked out so far. Below is my code.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

```
char s1[50], s2[50], s3[50];

printf("Enter 3 strings ");
scanf("%s %s %s", s1, s2, s3);

//THESE ARE NULL
char *argBB[] = { &s1, &s2, &s3, '\0'};
```

Comment: You say these are null. What are "these"? argBB? s1, s2, s3?

Comment: `scanf("%s %s %s", &s1, &s2, &s3);` => `scanf("%s %s %s", s1, s2, s3);`

Comment: Read the documentation of scanf and check the return value.

Comment: also, if you turn on warnings you will see other obvious problems

Comment: That array should be `char *argBB[] = { s1, s2, s3, NULL };`

Comment: `'\0'` is not a `char*` - it is a char

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider these are s1, s2, s3

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks. I think I had that initially but changed it for whatever reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.  For your scanf call, `%s` expects `char *` but your are passing in `char *[50]`.  You define the variable `argBB` to be a `char *[]`, but you initialized it with one three correct variables, and a constant char.  Here's a simplified version of a corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[20];

    printf("enter a string\n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("your string is %s\n", str);
    char *arg[] = {str, ""};
    printf("your string is still %s\n", arg[0]);
}
```